# Using for loop for isolation forest anomaly score

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataset with different groups separated by an `id` variable and I want to calculate and add the anomaly scores in the dataframe.

Here is an example dataset with three companies,

```
set.seed(1234)

id1 <- rep(23, 60)
n1 <- rnorm(n = 60, mean = 100, sd = 5.2)
g1 <- rnorm(n = 60, mean = 200, sd = 8)

id2 <- rep(34, 60)
n2 <- rnorm(n = 60, mean = 500, sd = 110)
g2 <- rnorm(n = 60, mean = 800, sd = 160)

id3 <- rep(3, 60)
n3 <- rnorm(n = 60, mean = 50, sd = 11)
g3 <- rnorm(n = 60, mean = 80, sd = 16)

id <- c(id1, id2, id3)
n <- c(n1, n2, n3)
g <- c(g1, g2, g3)

df <- data.frame(id, n, g)
rm(list = ls() [!ls() %in% "df"])
```

The first variable is the company `id`. Each company has 60 observations. The code I want to run on each company is as follows.

```
library(isofor)
mod <- iForest(X = df, 50, 10)
anomalyscore <- predict(mod, df)
df <- data.frame(df, anomalyscore)
```

However, to run the commands on each companies separately I would need a loop like this,

```
n <- 3
for (i in 1:n {
  mod <- iForest(X = df, 50, 10)
  anomalyscore <- predict(mod, df)
  df <- data.frame(df, anomalyscore)
}
```

**Question 1**
What's/are the mistake/s I did in the above loop? What it does is creating three anomaly score instead of one. I need one column of anomaly scores calculated separately for each company.

**Question 2**
Let's assume I do not know the number of observations for each company for sure, then how to adjust that in the loop?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Missing ) inside the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
df$anomalyscore <- NA
library(dplyr)
for (i in unique(df$id)) {
    mod <- iForest(X = filter(df, id == i), 50, 10)
    anomalyscore <- predict(mod, filter(df, id == i))
    df$anomalyscore[df$id == i] <- anomalyscore
    rm(anomalyscore)
}
```

Explanation:

> - Add a field `anomalyscore` with NA values
> - Iterate over `id` and generate scores only for that `id`
> - Update `anomalyscore` for that id

While this should address your question, you should look at `purrr` functions and `dplyr` to run a function on each group using `mutate` and `group_by`

Comment: Thank you for the solution and special thanks to show me the direction for further studying.